# Efficiently remove every 4th byte from a numpy.int32 array's data bytes

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, 24-bit

I have a big `numpy.int32` array, that can take 4GB or more. It's in fact a **24-bit integer array** (quite common in audio applications), but as `numpy.int24` doesn't exist, I used an `int32`.

I want to output this array's data as 24-bit, i.e. 3 bytes per number, to a file.

- This works (I found this "recipe" somewhere a while ago, but I can't find where anymore):

  ```
    import numpy as np
    x = np.array([[-33772,-2193],[13313,-1314],[20965,-1540],[10706,-5995],[-37719,-5871]], dtype=np.int32)
    data = ((x.reshape(x.shape + (1,)) >> np.array([0, 8, 16])) & 255).astype(np.uint8)
    print(data.tostring())

    # b'\x14|\xffo\xf7\xff\x014\x00\xde\xfa\xff\xe5Q\x00\xfc\xf9\xff\xd2)\x00\x95\xe8\xff\xa9l\xff\x11\xe9\xff'
  ```

  but the many `reshape` makes it inefficient when `x` is a few GB large: it takes a huge amount of unneeded RAM.
- Another solution would be to remove every 4th byte:

  ```
  s = bytes([c for i, c in enumerate(x.tostring()) if i % 4 != 3])

  # b'\x14|\xffo\xf7\xff\x014\x00\xde\xfa\xff\xe5Q\x00\xfc\xf9\xff\xd2)\x00\x95\xe8\xff\xa9l\xff\x11\xe9\xff'
  ```

  It works but I suspect that if `x` takes, say, 4 GB of RAM, this line would eat at least 8 GB of RAM, for both `s` and `x` (and maybe also `x.tostring()`?)

TL;DR: **How to efficiently (without using in RAM twice the size of the actual data) write to disk an int32 array, as a 24 bit array, by removing every 4th byte?**

Note: it's possible since the integers are in fact 24-bit, i.e. each value is < 2^23-1 in absolute value

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `x` is C-contiguous and that your platform is little-endian (would need little adjustments otherwise), you can do that like this:

```py
import numpy as np

# Input data
x = np.array([[-33772, -2193], [13313, -1314], [20965, -1540],
              [10706, -5995], [-37719, -5871]], dtype=np.int32)
# Make 24-bit uint8 view
x2 = np.ndarray(shape=x.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=x, offset=0, 
                strides=x.strides + (1,))  
print(x2.tostring())
# b'\x14|\xffo\xf7\xff\x014\x00\xde\xfa\xff\xe5Q\x00\xfc\xf9\xff\xd2)\x00\x95...
np.save('data.npy', x2)  # Save to disk
```

In this example, note that:

- we added a dimension: `x.shape + (3,)` is `(5, 2, 3)`.
- `x2` essentially is a view of `x`, that is, it uses the same data.
- The trick is in the strides. `x.strides + (1,)` is here `(8, 4, 1)`.
  Every new row of `x` advances 8 bytes with respect to its previous row, and every new column advances 4 bytes. In `x2`, I add a 1 to the strides so every item in the new innermost dimension advances 1 byte with respect to the previous one. If the shape of `x2` was (5, 2, 4) (that is, using `+ (4,)` instead of `+ (3,)`), it would be the same as `x`, but since it is (5, 2, 3), the last byte is just "skipped over".

---

You can restore it with:

```py
x2 = np.load('data.npy', mmap_mode='r')  # Use mmap to avoid using extra memory
x3 = np.zeros(x2.shape[:-1] + (4,), np.uint8)
x3[..., :3] = x2
del x2  # Release mmap
# Fix negative sign in last byte (could do this in a loop
# or in "batches" if you want to avoid the intermediate
# array from the "&" operation, or with Numba)
x3[..., 3] = np.where(x3[..., 2] & 128, 255, 0)
# Make int32 view
x4 = np.ndarray(x3.shape[:-1], np.int32, buffer=x3, offset=0, strides=x3.strides[:-1])
print(x4)
# [[-33772  -2193]
#  [ 13313  -1314]
#  [ 20965  -1540]
#  [ 10706  -5995]
#  [-37719  -5871]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdehesa, it works! I edited to add more details for future reference.

Comment: I see it works @jdehesa, but I don't see where the magic happens in `x2 = ...`: how does it make that every 4th byte is avoided? Can you explain more the stride part?

Comment: @Basj Yes, it's kind of implicit... So `x2` essentially is a view of `x`, that is, it uses the same data. The trick is in the `strides`. Every new row of `x` advances 8 bytes with respect to its previous row, and every new column advances 4 bytes. In `x2`, I add a `1` to the strides so every item in the new innermost dimension advances 1 byte with respect to the previous one. If the shape of `x2` was `(5, 2, 4)` (that is, using `+ (4,)` instead of `+ (3,)`), it would be the same as `x`, but since it is `(5, 2, 3)`, the last byte is just "skipped over", if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdehesa. I inserted your comment in the answer because it's really an important part, I hope it's ok for you. PS: I did a benchmark and your method and mine (see other answer) gave similar results both in terms of RAM usage and time spent.

Answer (score 2):

After some more fiddling, I found this to be working:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[-33772,-2193],[13313,-1314],[20965,-1540],[10706,-5995],[-37719,-5871]], dtype=np.int32)
x2 = x.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1,4)[:,:3]
print(x2.tostring())
# b'\x14|\xffo\xf7\xff\x014\x00\xde\xfa\xff\xe5Q\x00\xfc\xf9\xff\xd2)\x00\x95\xe8\xff\xa9l\xff\x11\xe9\xff'
```

Here is a time+memory benchmark:

```
import numpy as np, time
t0 = time.time()
x = np.random.randint(10000, size=(125_000_000, 2), dtype=np.int32)  # 125M * 2 * 4 bytes ~ 1GB of RAM
print('Random array generated in %.1f sec.' % (time.time() - t0))
time.sleep(5)  
# you can check the RAM usage in the task manager in the meantime...
t0 = time.time()
x2 = x.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1,4)[:,:3]
x2.tofile('test')
print('24-bit output file written in %.1f sec.' % (time.time() - t0))
```

Result:

> Random array generated in 4.6 sec.
> 24-bit output file written in 35.9 sec.

Also, only ~1GB has been used during the whole processing (monitored with Windows Task Manager)

---

@jdehesa's method gave similar results, i.e. if we use this line instead:

```
x2 = np.ndarray(shape=x.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=x, offset=0, strides=x.strides + (1,))
```

the RAM usage of the process also peaked at 1GB, and the time spent on `x2.tofile(...)` is ~37 sec.

Comment: This is so much simpler, I didn't realise you could just use `.view(np.uint8)` and it would do the right thing. Same goes for the restoring, after you fill the `np.uint8` array you can just do `.view(np.int32)`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got similar times to your 35 sec, but that seems way too slow for 750MB when my SSD can do 2GB/s. I can't imagine why it is so slow. So I decided to use **OpenCV**'s highly optimised SIMD code which reduces an RGBA8888 image to RGB888 by stripping every 4th byte of Alpha/transparency information - which is equivalent to converting 32-bit to 24-bit.

In order not to use too much extra memory, I did it in chunks of 1,000,000 stereo samples (6MB) at a time, and appended to the output file. It runs in under 1 sec and the files compare identical to that created by your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

def orig(x):
    x2 = x.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1,4)[:,:3]
    x2.tofile('orig.dat')

def chunked(x):
    BATCHSIZE = 1_000_000
    l = len(x)
    with open('test.dat', 'w') as file:
        for b in range(0,l,BATCHSIZE):
            s = min(BATCHSIZE,l-b)
            y = x[b:b+s,:].view(np.uint8).reshape(s*2,1,4) 
            z = cv2.cvtColor(y,cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
            # Append to file
            z.tofile(file)
            if b+s == l:
                break


# Repeatable randomness
np.random.seed(42)                                                                                         
# Create array of stereo samples
NSAMPLES = 125_000_000
x = np.random.randint(10000, size=(NSAMPLES, 2), dtype=np.int32)

# orig(x)
chunked(x)
```